# jQuery set class to inner div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set a class of radio-checked to a div and all previous divs on mouse over and remove on mouse out. The trouble is that it sets to the 'a' tag surrounding each of the div's.

Is there a way to set to inner div?

```
 $(function() {
    $('.radio-fx').live( "mouseenter", function() { // Handles the mouseover
            var $self = $(this);
            $self.addClass('radio-checked').prevAll().addClass('radio-checked');
            $self.nextAll().removeClass('radio-checked');
    }).live ( "mouseout", function() { // Handles the mouseout
            $(this).removeClass('radio').prevAll().removeClass('radio');
    });
});   

  <div class="voteGroup">
       <input type="radio" id="price_0" value="1" name="price" style="display: none;" class="radio-checked">
       <a href="#" class="radio-fx price radio-checked" title=" check me ">
              <div class="radio"></div>
       </a>
       <input type="radio" id="price_1" value="2" name="price" style="display: none;" class="radio-checked">
       <a href="#" class="radio-fx price radio-checked" title=" check me ">
              <div class="radio"></div></a>
       <input type="radio" id="price_2" value="3" name="price" style="display: none;" class="radio-checked">
       <a href="#" class="radio-fx price radio-checked" title=" check me ">
               <div class="radio"></div>
       </a>
       <input type="radio" id="price_3" value="4" name="price" style="display: none;" class="radio-checked">
       <a href="#" class="radio-fx price radio-checked" title=" check me ">
               <div class="radio"></div>
       </a>
       <input type="radio" id="price_4" value="5" name="price" style="display: none;" class="radio-checked" checked="checked">
       <a href="#" class="radio-fx price radio-checked" title=" check me ">
               <div class="radio-checked"></div>
       </a>
   </div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide us a working http://jsfiddle.net/ example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('.radio-fx').live( "mouseenter", function() { // Handles the mouseover
            var $self = $(this);
            $self.prevAll().andSelf().find('div').addClass('radio-checked');
            $self.nextAll().find('div').removeClass('radio-checked');
    }).live ( "mouseout", function() { // Handles the mouseout
            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().find('div').removeClass('radio-checked');
    });
});
```

By the way, `live` [is deprecated in latest versions of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/live/) - use `on` instead.

**Update** Here is the version that uses `on`:

```
$(function() {
    $('.radio-fx').on("mouseenter", function() { // Handles the mouseover
            var $self = $(this);
            $self.prevAll().andSelf().find('div').addClass('radio-checked');
            $self.nextAll().find('div').removeClass('radio-checked');
    }).on("mouseout", function() { // Handles the mouseout
            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().find('div').removeClass('radio-checked');
    });
});
```

jsFiddle [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/8HcKP/).

Comment: yeah will change over to .on(), had a few issues with it but will spend more time on it

Comment: I have changed this line and now when I hover the current one highlighted $self.children('div').addClass('radio-checked').prevAll().addClass('radio-checked');

Comment: Please see the update. Also added the version with `on` and working jsFiddle sample.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
$self.prevAll().andSelf().children('div').addClass('radio-checked');
```

It looks for the children of the previous elements.

The other lines should be:

```
$self.nextAll().children('div').removeClass('radio-checked'); 

$(this).prevAll().andSelf().children('div').removeClass('radio');
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, when I hover over the previous div now have the class applied but the current on I am on does not

Comment: Good point. I've split it into two statements that should work.

Comment: Figured how to do it in a single line :)

Comment: great thanks that works, any idea how I would reset it back to class radio on mouse out if not clicked?